# Google Cloud storage - getting objects via wildcard

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

So, using gsutil, I can run this:

```
gsutil ls gs://<my bucket name>/AR7020014/agent_directory_photos/adp_42643_*
```

and get a list of filenames. I would really love to do this in my PHP code. I have tried
this:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Storage( $authenticated_client );

$params = [ 'prefix' => 'AR7020014/agent_directory_photos/adp_42643_*', maxResults 10 ];

$objects = $service->objects->listObjects(<my bucket name>, $params);
```

but the returned object set contains no items. I don't want to do a directory scan, the number of files in this particular folder can get very large.

Answer (score 1):

The GCS objects listing prefix is a plain string, not supporting wildcards. gsutil implements wildcarding through a combination of prefix requests (if the request the user specifies happens to start with non-wildcard characters) and client-side filtering for the wildcard match. For example, `gsutil ls gs://bucket/abc[1-3]*` would be implemented by sending a prefix="abc" request, and then filtering the responses locally for those that match the full wildcard expression.

To do it from PHP you would have to implement something similar yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, I literally just figured that out from my experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage APIs do not support wildcard characters. You can simulate this using the `prefix` and `delimiter` params.

```
$params = [ 
    'prefix' => 'AR7020014/agent_directory_photos/adp_42643_', 
    'delimiter' => '/',
    maxResults => 10 ];
```

This parameter will cause `listObjects()` to return all objects that start with the `prefix` value.

Comment: and what if the wildcard is on the other side... e.g. you want `*adp_42643`  - it just can't be done (wildcard)

Comment: @Griff I am not sure. The API spec declares delimiter as a string. I am not sure what happens if you set the delimiter to **adp_42643**. It might return all blobs that start with **prefix** and end in **adp_42643**. Try it and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just tested this out, and got a confirmation from Mike Schwartz. The way to make this work is by making the prefix just the folder name ("AR7020014/agent_directory_photos"), and adding a new parameter:

```
'marker' => 'adp_42643'
```

The limitation for me is that this will also return files similar to 'adp_42644', etc. Since I know that I'll always have only 10 or 12 files that match what I want, I set:

```
'maxResults' => 15
```

Then I have a set of up to 15 Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject objects to walk through to get what I really want. Not as nice as a wildcard would be, but it'll do.